# MS Access - Multiple Distinct Report Parameters

Tags: ms-access, parameters, reporting

This is my first contribution for stack exchange. I take to feed-back and criticism well so please make sure I can learn from it if I'm not following correct protocol, community etiquette, etc

I work for a health care company that sometimes performs biometric screenings. I am tasked with creating a simple back-up system for our current cloud-based application. The system has to accomplish the following:

1. Enter participant into a member table using an entry form
2. Pull-up the member and record biometric data using a biometric entry form (12 metrics in total)
3. Allow user to print a report with member demographics, along with biometric detail in this order:

   - Column 1: Screening Measure (Height, Weight, waist, etc)
   - Column 2: Current Biometric Results
   - Column 3: Prior Biometrics (this will come from a data feed and will prepopulate a biometrics table (linked to participation table on participant id. There may be multiple periods for one individual)

In 99% of all situations, a participant will have 1 set of readings for 1 year period (1 for 2016, 1 for 2017, etc). Ideally, I would like to have a year parameter for column 2 and additionally for column 3. When the year is selected from the parameter the biometric values recorded in that year will populate the corresponding column.

My question is, would someone be able to help point me towards resources that help me understand how to tie data to specific parameters in a MS Access Report. Anything is extremely helpful!

FWIW, my short term solution is to build multiple queries to the effect of:

- Query 1: Select * from Biometrics where year ='2017' > Most Current
- Query 2: Select * from Biometrics where year = '2016' > historical

Bring both sets of results into print form. This will work for now, but I really want to have the ability to select which data based on the parameter in the report.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'tie query results to parameters in a MS Access Report'. Don't you want to open a report filtered to specific parameters? Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html and http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html

Comment: I edited my post so hopefully more clear. Thanks. I'll review the links that you sent me June7 and see if they get me where I need to go. Thanks for taking the time!